# NightmareJS asynchronous operations in a loop, wait for everything to be done

Tags: gulp, nightmare

I have a gulp task that uses [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) to visit a series of URLs, extract SVGs from them, process them and output them.

```js
gulp.task('export', done => {
  const path = require('path');
  const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
  const nightmare = new Nightmare();
  const urls = ['http://one.com', 'http://two.org', 'http://three.net'];

  async function exportPDFs (items) {
    for (url of items) {
      const filename = path.parse(url).name;
      const selector = 'svg';
      await nightmare
        .goto(url)
        .wait(selector)
        .evaluate(selector => {
          let content;
          // Extract SVG from the page
          return content;
        }, selector)
        .then(
          svg => {
            // Heavy operation that takes long
            // How do I wait for this properly?
            processThing(filename);
            outputThing(filename);
          },
          err => console.error('Page evaluation failed', err)
        );
    }
    await nightmare.end().then(() => done()); // ???
  }

  exportPDFs(urls);
});
```

How can I make it wait for the processing and outputting on each iteration, and at the end of all of them end the gulp task with `done()`?

Currently it ends before saving the last PDF:

```
Starting 'export'...
one.pdf saved
two.pdf saved
Finished 'export' after 3.2 s
three.pdf saved
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `processThing` and `outputThing` into promise. Then chain them like this,

```
.evaluate(()=>/*The code*/)
.then(processThing)
.then(outputThing)
.catch(e=>/*deal with errors*/)
```